# Ruby Merge List of Hashes & Get Average

Tags: ruby

I have the following list of hashes:

```
[{"day":3,"count":2},{"day":1,"count":2},{"day":1,"count":2},{"day":2,"count":2},{"day":1,"count":2},{"day":4,"count":2},{"day":5,"count":2},{"day":6,"count":2},{"day":4,"count":2},{"day":4,"count":2},{"day":3,"count":2},{"day":3,"count":2},{"day":2,"count":2},{"day":6,"count":2},{"day":0,"count":2},{"day":5,"count":2},{"day":0,"count":2},{"day":5,"count":2},{"day":4,"count":2},{"day":1,"count":2},{"day":0,"count":2},{"day":0,"count":2},{"day":2,"count":2},{"day":2,"count":2},{"day":2,"count":2},{"day":1,"count":2},{"day":6,"count":2},{"day":5,"count":2},{"day":3,"count":2},{"day":2,"count":2},{"day":2,"count":2},{"day":1,"count":2},{"day":5,"count":2},{"day":4,"count":2},{"day":2,"count":2}]
```

I want to merge together all the keys that have the same "day" value and then get the mean average of the second key/value pair's average.

So for example, my final output should look like:

```
[{"day":0, "count": 2}, {"day":1, "count": 2}, {"day":3, "count": 2}, {"day":4, "count": 2}, {"day":5, "count": 2}, {"day":6, "count": 2}, {"day":7, "count": 2},]
```

The count average would actually be calculated (not always "2"), I was just using two as an example.

Comment: Did you mean 'the average of the second key/value pair's **value**'?  In you're example, they're all `2`. Presumably this won't always be the case? And when you say 'average', is it mean, median or mode you're after?

Comment: Correct, they won't always be two. I just threw those in. And I'd like the mean. Thanks.

Comment: Also note, your hashes aren't valid. To use the `key:value` notation, the key should be a symbol, not a string.

Comment: @Kal: They're valid JSON; `JSON#parse` and done.

Comment: You might consider whether it might make more sense for the result to be `[{0 => 2}, {1 => 2},...]`.  In framing questions for SO, try to avoid the need for readers to scroll horizontally.  In this case just put each array on multiple lines.  Two other things: pare down your question to the essentials (here an array of, say, five hashes would be sufficient) and use input data that elaborates.  Here you've put 2's everywhere, which is just plain lazy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# group the list into sublists sharing the same day
data.group_by { |element| element['day'] }.map { |day, element_list|
  # for each day, return a new object
  {
    day:   day,
    # extract the count from all the elements in the sublist,
    # then add them together and divide by number of elements
    # (convert to float to avoid integral division)
    count: element_list.map { |element| element['count'] }.
             reduce(:+).to_f / element_list.size
  }
}
```

Comment: I updated my answer to flagrantly steal your use of `group_by`. Much less code than the `reduce` method I originally used.

Comment: @Amadan I want to take you out for a fish supper for providing this answer :)

Answer (score 2):

This would work, assuming your collection of hashes is called `data`:

```
days = data.group_by{|record| record["day"] }
days.map do |day, records|
  {day: day, count: records.map{|record| record["count"] }.average}
end
```